# How to change default UserName for Network Super Admin WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I have created multisite in WordPress. While creating the site I have given `admin` username for Network admin. Now I want to change the username of Network admin(Superuser).

I have tried the following steps:

1. Find `wp_users` table and change `old username` with `new username`;
2. FInd `wp_sitemeta` table and and edit the `site_admins` row as `a:1:{i:0;s:5:”new username”;}`

After doing this I am able to login successfully but the issue is that the top menubar of `wp-admin` is not displaying.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Is 1 the ID of the account you want grant super admin to? If not, you've just made someone else a super admin.

Comment: Nope, It's taken for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must delete the old one and create a new one. 
Steps with [wp-cli](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/create/):

1) create a new user:

```
wp user create superadminuser your@email.com --role=administrator --user_pass=passwordsupersafe
```

2) grant super admin role to new user

```
wp super-admin add superadminuser
```

3) login with superadminuser and delete the old admin. Maybe change the email of superadminuser to the one admin had.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will try it.

Comment: I have done it by following this solution https://agreda.com/2013/04/how-to-change-wordpress-admin-username/ but your answer also works.